# Notebook internal WIFI slow vs external WIFI fast

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, speed, isp

My internet through my internal wifi (intel wireless-n 1030) on my laptop slowed down 2-3 weeks ago. I used to download 2 MB/s. Now it is 20KB/s and barely reaches 150KB/s. Youtube buffers sometimes at 144p. I used to watch 1080P. It was really wierd because my other devices were fast. I tried changing my MAC address (MadMAC) to check if my ISP is slowing my connection to no avail. I changed the router's channel to a unique one to no avail. I bought a cheap usb WIFI. And voila 2 MB/s speed on the external.

I got worried that my WIFI adapter got damaged. I even downgraded to stock driver.

I tested wifi speed through my nexus 5's hotspot (4G). I got the same speed on both my internal wifi and external wifi at 500 KB/s. So I can safely eliminate that the hardware is damaged.

My question: Is it possible that my ISP can slow my connection even when I am using different MAC address, different ip address, and different wifi display name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by changing ISP's router. It was terrible.

I recommend buying SurfBoard SB6121 + any TPlink wireless router.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like the problem isn't with your ISP, if an external card is working at the nominal speeds I doubt it could be them. If they were going to throttle your connection, it would affect all of your devices.

If you downgraded your driver to your WiFi Card, the external one is working and nothing changed as the speed decrease happened, maybe your card is damaged.

Comment: Did you read paragraph 3? If I connect through a wifi hotspot, the speed is the same for both the internal and external at 500 KB/s.

Comment: Well, it looks like something weird is going on considering your nexus is working a little differently. Maybe it's the channel, or wifi settings on your router.

Comment: It's definitely not your ISP. I can guarantee you that.

Comment: There is one more thing. The notebook is from Europe. The external wifi is from US. I am currently living in the US. Is there any difference in the manufacturing of European wifi and US wifi? Btw thanks a lot for taking the time to reply to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

What signal strength do you get on the internal WiFi adapter? 
If it is poor in a location where the USB adapter is strong, it may be the antenna which is damaged. They usually run up around the screen bezel, so they are easy to damage with a knock.

What are the other parameters of your WiFi network?

- 2GHz or 5GHz?
- a/b/g/n/ac?
- neighboring WiFi networks?

Comment: signal is 5/5 all time on both wifi adapters. The network is 2GHz and uses n technology (broadcasts g/n). All neighboring WIFI networks are using one of these channels 1, 6, 8, 11. I am using 3.